# Multithreaded service running batch file via CreateProcess()

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, windows-services, batch-file

SEE UPDATE AT END

I am attempting to run the following batch file (named boot_time.bat, in the same directory as the .exe):

```
@echo off
cd %1
For /F %%I in ('Cscript boot_time.vbs //Nologo') Do Set var=%%I
set DATETIME=%var:~0,4%/%var:~4,2%/%var:~6,2% %var:~8,2%:%var:~10,2%:%var:~12,2%.%var:~15,3%
echo %DATETIME%
```

The batch file takes one argument, it's current working directory. It's purpose is to retrieve the system boot time via the boot_time.vbs script and format it into a common date format. For completenesses sake, here are the contents of the vbs file:

```
set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
set colOS = objWMI.InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")
for each objOS in colOS
    Wscript.Echo objOS.LastBootUpTime
NEXT
```

While I appreciate comments on alternative (read: simpler) methods to retrieve the system boot time, rest assured I have explored all avenues (that I have come across) and none match the requirements for the system.

Now, the crux of the issue. When I attempt to run the .bat file via C++, CreateProcess() returns 1, but the batch file is not run (I have verified this by replacing the contents of boot_time.bat with a simple 'start calc' which still refuses to run). The offending code:

```
//run batch file
stringstream commandStream;
commandStream << "/C "                           //close window on termination
         << "\"" << batchFile.c_str() << "\" "   //batch file path inside ""
         << "\"" << processPath.c_str() << "\" " //working directory as argument inside ""
         << ">"                                  //redirect
         << "\"" << outFile.c_str() << "\"";     //output file inside ""

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

BOOL ret = CreateProcess("cmd.exe", const_cast<char*>(commandStream.str().c_str()), NULL, NULL, TRUE, NULL, NULL, processPath.c_str(), &si, &pi);

WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

The paths and command line arguments are all fine (I can debug print them and paste into cmd.exe, where they work as expected). Stepping through the code, CreateProcess() returns 1 and everything runs as normal, however the batch file never gets run.

In my many hours searching the interwebs I have come across whisperings of issues when it comes to running a batch file from a service, but I:

a) can no longer find said whisperings,
b) would think that CreateProcess("cmd.exe",...) is not running a batch file, but an exe, and leaving the rest up to the command prompt.

So, any idea what is going on?

Oh, I'm running VC++6

UPDATE 1:
If I tick 'Allow service to interact with desktop', and change CreateProcess() to not hide the console window (via CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE), I get a split second of the command prompt popping up. So, CreateProcess() is creating a cmd.exe process, but cmd.exe is refusing to run the batch file.

UPDATE 2:
After Gabe's suggestion I rethought my process and simplified it somewhat in an attempt to track down the culprit. I've removed the batch file, and consolodated it into the VBS file, which is now:

```
set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
set colOS = objWMI.InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")
Dim bootTime
for each objOS in colOS
   bootTime = objOS.LastBootUpTime

bootTime = mid(bootTime,1,4) & "/" & Mid(bootTime,5,2) & "/" & Mid(bootTime,7,2) & " " & Mid(bootTime,9,2) & ":" & Mid(bootTime,11,2) & ":" & Mid(bootTime,13,2) & "." & Mid(bootTime,16,3)
Wscript.Echo bootTime
NEXT
```

The c++ code is largely unchanged, just modified the command line to call WScript.exe instead of cmd.exe. I'm getting the fully qualified paths for all files, which leads to the following string:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wscript.exe" //Nologo "c:\<repository_dir>\boot_time.vbs" >"C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\rts5FD.tmp"
```

(repository_dir is intentional to leave out names). Also, I'm only using Wscript to test, as it pops up a message box. Proper usage will be with Cscript.exe, with output redirected to the temp file.

CreateProcess does not cause the message box to pop up, running direct from command line does.

Comment: First of all, does it work if you run your program from the command line instead of as a service? Second, you should print `commandStream` and verify that running that from your program's working directory works.

Comment: One obvious problem is that the VBS script won't execute if it's on a different drive letter from the service's working directory unles you use `cd /d %1`.

Comment: I'll add the /d, thanks (but the script is in the same folder, so that's not an issue at present).  Yes, I tried running the commandStream output from the working directory (and any other directory, as the cd %1 will change to the working directory) and it worked fine.

Comment: How do you know the batch file isn't running? If you remove `echo off` and put a `pause` at the end of it, do you see it executing?

Comment: What if you use `system` instead of `CreateProcess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input, however I've managed to fix the issue. It seems the problem stemmed from the fact that the service from which i'm calling CreateProcess() is running as LocalSystem. CreateProcess() creates the new process under the same user, where I needed it to be running as the logged in user. Here is the code to get the current user, and use their token in CreateProcessAsUser():

```
//retrieve the user token via an open process
HANDLE hToken = NULL;                
HANDLE hProcess = NULL;
DWORD dwProcessId = NULL;

//user 'explorer.exe' as the process to search for
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
ZeroMemory(&pe32,sizeof(pe32));

HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,NULL);

pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32); 

if(Process32First(hSnapshot,&pe32))
{
    do
    {
        if(!strcmp(pe32.szExeFile,"explorer.exe"))
        {
            dwProcessId = pe32.th32ProcessID;
            break;
        }

    }while(Process32Next(hSnapshot,&pe32));
}

if( dwProcessId ) 
{
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,TRUE, dwProcessId );
    if( hProcess) 
    {
        OpenProcessToken(hProcess,  TOKEN_EXECUTE | TOKEN_READ | TOKEN_QUERY | 
                                    TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
                                    TOKEN_WRITE | TOKEN_DUPLICATE, 
                                    &hToken);
        CloseHandle( hProcess );
    }
    else
    {
        error = _T("Could not open process 'explorer.exe'");
        return false;
    }
}
else
{
    error = _T("Could not retrieve process id for 'explorer.exe'");
    return false;
}

if (hToken != NULL)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    if (CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, "cmd.exe", const_cast<char*>(command.c_str()), NULL, NULL, TRUE, 
                                            CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) == 0)
    {
        tstringstream err;
        err << "CreateProcessAsUser() failed with error: " << GetLastError();
        error = err.str();
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return false;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
    CloseHandle( hToken );
}
else
{
    error = _T("Token retrieved from 'explorer.exe' is NULL");
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Where, in my case, command.c_str() points to the following string:

```
/C ""C:\WINDOWS\System32\Cscript.exe" //Nologo "c:\<repository_dir>\boot_time.vbs" >"C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\rts452.tmp""
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Read closely this line from [MSDN's description of CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx):

> Because argv[0] is the module name, C programmers generally repeat the module name as the first token in the command line.

This imples that your code should be:

```
commandStream << "cmd.exe /C "
```

See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/15/597984.aspx.

However, I must add that I would shoot somebody I found using C++ to run a batch file to execute a VBScript in order to process its output. Since the batch file is doing nothing but string manipulation, why can't you do that string manipulation in VBS or C++?

Alternatively, you can avoid the batch file and just call `cscript` directly with this code:

```
set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2") 
set colOS = objWMI.InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem") 
for each objOS in colOS 
    t = objOS.LastBootUpTime 
next
wscript.echo left(t, 4) & "/" & mid(t, 5, 2) & "/" & mid(t, 7, 2) & " " & _
             mid(t, 9, 2) & ":" & mid(t, 11, 2) & ":" & mid(t, 13, 2) & "." & _
             mid(t, 16, 3)
```

Another option is to query the `System\System Up Time` performance counter and subtract its value from the current time.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it still refuses to run. Attempts to defend my methods follow.

Comment: I could call the WMI commands directly from code, however the header files are from a later version of the windows SDK we use. I could use the wmic command, but this code is requried to run on W2k machines, where wmic does not exist. Therefore the only way to get the requried data is through a VBScript. The reason I'm manipulating the string in the batch file is that my VBS knowledge is minimal, and a requirement is that we can at some point in the future change the way the batch file retrieves the data without having to modify the c++ parsing code.

Comment: You don't need the SDK's header files. You can just take the declarations from the proper SDK and put them into your own `.cpp` or `.h` file.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, made me rethink my process, which is always good. Please see my edit to the original question. Unfortunately we cannot rely on using the current system time to derive the boot time, as time synchronisation software may have corrected the system time (and we require uncorrected boot time).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the C++ code to do all this.

Like most C++ COM code it gets quite verbose. But here you go:

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>

#include <windows.h>
#include <wbemidl.h>
# pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

void com_init() {
  HRESULT hr;
  hr = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("COM Error");
  }
  hr =  CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL);
  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    CoUninitialize();
    throw std::runtime_error("COM Error");
  }
}

std::wstring wmi_last_boot_time() {
  IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;
  IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;
  IEnumWbemClassObject *pEnum = NULL;
  IWbemClassObject *pEach = NULL;

  std::wstring lastBootUpTime;

  try {
    HRESULT hr;
    // Get WMI object
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
      throw std::runtime_error("WMI: Unable to create WbemLocator");
    }
    hr = pLoc->ConnectServer(L"root\\cimv2", NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, 0, &pSvc);
    if (FAILED(hr))  {
      throw std::runtime_error("WMI: Unable to connect");
    }

    // Exec query
    hr = pSvc->ExecQuery(L"WQL", L"SELECT LastBootUpTime FROM Win32_OperatingSystem", 0, 0, &pEnum);
    if (FAILED(hr))  {
      throw std::runtime_error("WMI: Query failed");
    }

    // Fetch result
    VARIANT value;
    ULONG uCount;
    hr = pEnum->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pEach, &uCount);
    if (FAILED(hr) || uCount == 0)  {
      throw std::runtime_error("WMI: Can't fetch result");
    }

    hr = pEach->Get(L"LastBootUpTime", 0, &value, 0, 0);
    if (FAILED(hr))  {
      throw std::runtime_error("WMI: Can't get LastBootUpTime");
    }

    if (value.vt != VT_BSTR) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Expected string");
    }

    lastBootUpTime = value.bstrVal;

  } catch (std::runtime_error &) {
    if (pLoc)  pLoc->Release();
    if (pSvc)  pSvc->Release();
    if (pEnum) pEnum->Release();
    if (pEach) pEach->Release();
    throw;
  }

  pLoc->Release();
  pSvc->Release();
  pEnum->Release();
  pEach->Release();

  return lastBootUpTime;
}


int main() {
  try {
    // Initialize COM. Do this only once
    com_init();

    // Get last boot time
    std::wstring str = wmi_last_boot_time();

    // Reformat time
    std::wcout << str.substr(0, 4) << "/" << str.substr(4, 2) << "/" << str.substr(6, 2) << " "
               << str.substr(8, 2) << ":" << str.substr(10, 2) << ":" << str.substr(12, 2) << "."
               << str.substr(15, 3) << std::endl;


    // Uninitialize COM
    CoUninitialize();

  } catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I think you can get this working on vc6. wbemidl.h contains COM interfaces definitions that you could probably generate with `midl` or perhaps even use the headers from a recent SDK.

Unfortunately I don't even have vc6 installed.